# How to click an element visible after hovering with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover

I want to click a button which is visible after hovering. Its html is:

```
<span class="info"></span>
```

I used this code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "http://example.com"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("info")
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hov.perform()
element.click()
```

It's not working though. I got a an error connected with the last line of code `element.click():`

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: \
u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The errors are what exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I bet you should wait for the element until it becomes visible.

Three options:

- call `time.sleep(n)`
- use `WebDriverWait` like it's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176713/771848) and [here](http://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2012/07/12/how-to-webdriverwait/)

I'd go with the second option.

UPD:

On this particular site hovering via selenium didn't work at all, so the only option was to click on the button using js via `execute_script`:

```
driver.execute_script('$("span.info").click();')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but I've tried `time.sleep` actually and it seems it's not the case.

Comment: Ok, `WebDriverWait` should work, let me know if you'll have problems with it.

Comment: Sorry for late answer but needed to read your links through. I still think my issue differs as the element/button in my case is visible/accessible all the time. So I can hover over it instantly as the page loads. There is no ajax/js code execution in between. I'm just unable to correctly localize the elements either with `find_element_by` or `xpath`.

Comment: got it, could you provide the link to the page, so I can find a workaround for you?

Comment: I'd love to. For 'security' reasons I think I'm better off not posting it. Can we possibly contact via email?