# how to extract data from autocomplete box with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from a search box, you can see a good example on  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page%27)

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(response.url)                
    city = driver.find_element_by_id('searchInput') 
    city.click()
    city.clear()
    city.send_keys('a')
    time.sleep(1.5) #waiting for ajax to load              
    selen_html = driver.page_source
    #print selen_html.encode('utf-8')
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=selen_html)
    ajaxWikiList = hxs.select('//div[@class="suggestions"]')
    items=[]
    for city in ajaxWikiList:
        item=TestItem()
        item['ajax'] = city.select('/div[@class="suggestions-results"]/a/@title').extract()
        items.append(item)
    print items
```

Xpath expression is ok, I checked on a static page. If I uncomment the line that prints out scrapped html code the code for the box shows at the end of the file. But for some reason I can't extract data from it with the above code? I must miss something since I tried 2 different sources, wikipedia page is just another source where I can't get these data extracted.
Any advice here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `.page_source` which in your case contains an empty `suggestions` div, get the `innerHTML` of the element and pass it to the `Selector`:

```
selen_html = driver.find_element_by_class_name('suggestions').get_attribute('innerHTML')

hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=selen_html)
suggestions = hxs.select('//div[@class="suggestions-results"]/a/@title').extract()
for suggestion in suggestions:
    print suggestion
```

Outputs:

```
Animal
Association football
Arthropod
Australia
AllMusic
African American (U.S. Census)
Album
Angiosperms
Actor
American football
```

Note that it would be better to use selenium [`Waits`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) feature to wait for the element to be accessible/visible, see:

- [How can I get Selenium Web Driver to wait for an element to be accessible, not just present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161773/how-can-i-get-selenium-web-driver-to-wait-for-an-element-to-be-accessible-not-j)
- [Selenium waitForElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement)

Also, note that `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated, use [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) instead.