# Python Selenium - Can click element directly when it was present no need waiting for page load complete?

Tags: python, selenium

Current scenario is some page needs more time to loading. I want click an element when it was present, But no need wait for whole page load complete. How to fix this problem? Can provide some demo or example?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161773/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `driver.get()` call is blocking. There is a [beta feature](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#-Beta-_load_fast_preference) in the Firefox driver that could work combined with [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'someid'))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I just tired your code on "https://www.box.com". Just take "Login" button as example. I want click it when it was present no need waiting page load complete. I just tried the code but the the page still loading after "Login" button present.

Comment: In fact I don't think this method works. It is mainly for setting the waiting-timeout, but the main action (click) will be executed with the same dynamics as if we have just called the find element function.