# Enter key press is not working in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, keypress

I have a scenario which involves pressing `Enter` key in the webpage. For `Chrome` my code works fine but when it comes to `Firefox` my code is not working. Please help me with an idea so that I can automate `Enter` key press in `Selenium` `Python` for `Firefox` driver.

Below are the codes that I have used.

```
browser1.find_element_by_xpath("path").send_keys(u'\ue007')
browser1.find_element_by_xpath("path").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Are you specifying to Selenium that you're going to be using Firefox as the browser? `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: Why are you not using click instead as `browser1.find_element_by_xpath("path").click()`??

Comment: Or could you us tell for what purpose you want to use this??

Comment: ya.. i am specifying. And importantly i need to use it to enter values in a field. The requirement itself is like press enter after entering each value.

Comment: So what is the problem occurred with your code?? Is there any exception during sendKeys??

Comment: @BhuvaneshwariKumarRaja - Please post the link of the webpage you are working on and also your code. This will make it easier for people to help you and give you an answer.

Comment: am restricted to give the link of the webpage am working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_name("Value").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Note that RETURN = '\ue006'

**EDIT**

Keep [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) always in mind when programming WebDriver. Be mindful of the Programming Language Preference button near the top.

**EDIT**

Try

```
WebElement anElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Value")
anElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

If you have changed the selection criteria to wait for the element to be enabled then keep that change.  When Selenium is having timing issues I find that separating the action from the find often helps.

Comment: Post your code and the console log showing the error.

Comment: Hi, I have called the enter key press code twice. Its working now. Thanks

    browser1.find_element_by_xpath("path").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

calling the above line twice works fine.

Comment: @BhuvaneshwariKumarRaja It is likely that on the first pass the WebElement returned by the find_element_by_name is not ready to receive the input. You should fix this.  One way is to add criteria to wait for the WebElement to be enabled.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161773/how-can-i-get-selenium-web-driver-to-wait-for-an-element-to-be-accessible-not-j) SO Q&A.

Comment: I have even added webdriver wait, even then if i use enter key press two times only it is working.