# Selenium Webdriver - Python - leboncoin - pb to select a button with an accent

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to fill in a form automatically on the following website: 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/'

I have recorded a script with Selenium IDE.

I have a function to connect automatically by clicking on the button 'Se connecter' and filling my pwd and username. It works fine

I have set up specific credential for this topic
email: thecoingood@gmail.com 
pwd: thecoingood1

the code is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Connectionwebdriver2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.base_urldr = "https://compteperso.leboncoin.fr/account/index.html"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_connectionwebdriver2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_urldr)
        driver.find_element_by_name("st_username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("st_username").send_keys("thecoingood@gmail.com ")
        driver.find_element_by_name("st_passwd").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("st_passwd").send_keys("thecoingood1")
        driver.find_element_by_id("connect_button").click()
        #driver.get("https://www2.leboncoin.fr/ai?ca=15_s")

        my_annonce = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)\
        .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Supprimer")))
        my_annonce.click()
        #time.sleep(10)
        #driver.find_element_by_link_text("Supprimer").click()
        #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='//https://compteperso.leboncoin.fr/account/index.html?ca=12_s' and contains(.,'posez une annonce')]"))).click()
        #Select(driver.find_element_by_id("category")).select_by_visible_text('Locations')
        #Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cat10')).select()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Once connected, I am redirected to
https://compteperso.leboncoin.fr/account/index.html?ca=12_s
(question: is the object used in selenium updated with this new address or still sticks with the initial one which may create the issue)

when I try to click on the

```
<a href="//www2.leboncoin.fr/ai?ca=15_s">Déposez une annonce</a>
```

with this code

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"Déposez une annonce").click()
```

Nothing happens (no error).

I believe this is related to the fact the link is not yet visible.
I have tried to add time.sleep() and also read

[How can I get Selenium Web Driver to wait for an element to be accessible, not just present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161773/how-can-i-get-selenium-web-driver-to-wait-for-an-element-to-be-accessible-not-j)

but coud not resolve this. I could add a direct link to the page, but I would like to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in the website you linked, I could only see "Dépose**r** une annonce"

Comment: @OlivierHoen Do you have a demo set of credentials. Without the valid credentials we can't locate the intended _webelement_

Comment: I have set up specific credential to connect to the page
https://compteperso.leboncoin.fr/account/index.html
email: thecoingood@gmail.com
pwd: thecoingood

the point is that once connected, there is a redirection to a new page
https://compteperso.leboncoin.fr/account/index.html?ca=12_s
You can see that one button is "Déposez une annonce"

Comment: Doesn't lets me log in error as `Votre identifiant ou mot de passe est incorrect.`

Comment: Sorty, pwd is thecoingood1

Comment: Sorry the pwd is thecoingood1

Comment: @OlivierHoen , update the title as for now "Selenium Webdriver - Python -" doesn't reflect your problem

Comment: Can you update your sample code to its current state (with the attempt to click "Déposez une annonce")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question to click on the *tab* / *link* with text as **Déposez une annonce** you can use the following line of code :

- To click the `TAB` with text as **Déposez une annonce** use :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='deposer']/a[contains(@href,'//www2.leboncoin.fr/ai?ca=') and contains(.,'une annonce')]"))).click()
  ```
- To click the `BUTTON` with text as **Déposez une annonce** use :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='create']/a[contains(@href,'//www2.leboncoin.fr/ai?ca=') and contains(.,'une annonce')]"))).click()
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your code but still the same issue. I have updated the question, with credential created specifically for this question. The issue may be related to the accent or the the fact the page used to search the link is not exactly the one which is defined the set up. Thanks

Comment: It works perfectly (both options). Thanks. For my education, you would say that my code was not working because of the accent?